# How to pull a variable file from S3 in Ansible

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible

My requirement is that I want to dynamically include a variable file in my Ansible script. I can do that by putting following in my ansible task-

```
- name: Include vars file
  include_vars: vars/dev.yml

- name: Some other task
  cp: copy something
```

Above works if I keep the `dev.yml` in my vars directory. Now I actually do not want to put the dev.yml in the directory, I want to pull it from S3 and then use the variable in it. Something like below-

```
- name: Get dev file
  s3:
    bucket: bucket_name
    object: object_name
    dest: "dest_directory"    ## Here I want the destination to be vars/dev.yml
    mode: get
    aws_access_key: "{{ s3.aws_access_key }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ s3.aws_secret_key }}"

- name: Include vars file
  include_vars: vars/dev.yml

- name: Some other task that uses vars in dev.yml
  template: render some template using vars in dev.yml and copy to server
```

The above will actually not work. How do I do this?

Comment: And why this will not work? Just keep in mind that dev.yml should be fetched on control host, not managed host.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov - Ok I got it, Thanks. But currently first I am using `s3` module to download file on managed host then using `fetch` module to copy that to control host, then use that to load variables. Is there any way to directly fetch file from s3 to control host?

Comment: tried with `delegate_to`?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov - Thanks, that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks [Konstantin Suvorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2795592/konstantin-suvorov) for help. I just needed to add [`delegate_to`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) in my task.

```
- name: Get dev file
  s3:
    bucket: bucket_name
    object: object_name
    dest: vars/dev.yml
    mode: get
    aws_access_key: "{{ s3.aws_access_key }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ s3.aws_secret_key }}"
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Include vars file
  include_vars: vars/dev.yml
```